# Laravel Pagination the data not change with the render() in the blade

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have this problem, when i manually create a paginator in laravel for show 100 products,  in the view the page displays the data and it is fine, but if i put a limit , example i want 10 element per page, he show the ten elements in the firs page, when i click in next the second page show me the same ten elements, the data don't changes , why?

Controller:

```
  public function show()
    {


        $client = new Client([
            // Base URI is used with relative requests
            'base_uri' => 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/59bec4d926000046015261a7',
            // You can set any number of default request options.
            'timeout' => 2.0,
        ]);

        $response = $client->request('GET', '');
        $code = $response->getStatusCode()
        $products = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

        }

     $products =  new Paginator($products, 10 ,
       Paginator::resolveCurrentPage(),
       ['path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()]);


        return view('products/list', compact('products'));

    }
```

View

```
@extends('layout.master')

@section('content')
<h2> Products</h2>
<ul>

    @if($products)
    @foreach($products as $product)
       <li> {{ $product->name}} - {{ $product->value}}</li>
        @endforeach
        @endif

</ul>
{{$products->render()}}

@endsection
```

Example of Result with array of ten element , 3 per page 
// this is a example with invented information.

```
array {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

Page 1 

 0 - 0 
 1 - 1
 2 - 2

Page 2 // the data dont change , why ?

 0 - 0 
 1 - 1
 2 - 2
```

Comment: Which Paginator class are you using? If it's a custom class, please show us the code

Comment: @Paras i am explain me bad, i use the method for  Manually Creating A Paginator of laravel "Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator", link https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination, in the current code i use the Paginator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No magic, paginators will call your controller function for every page. The request will have the pagination information in it. It is your job to actually select and slice the page. The paginator simply presents it... which is a big part of the work...

```
   // DB::select returns an array, thus we have to build the paginator ourselves...
    $comm = DB::select('select bla bla bla from comments where this and that... 
                        order by approved ASC');

    // this basically gets the request's page variable... or defaults to 1
    $page = Paginator::resolveCurrentPage('page') ?: 1;

    // Assume 15 items per page... so start index to slice our array
    $startIndex = ($page - 1) * 15;

    // Length aware paginator needs a total count of items... to paginate properly
    $total = count($comm);

    // Eliminate the non relevant items...
    $results = array_slice($comm, $startIndex, 15);

    $comments =  new LengthAwarePaginator($results, $total, 15, $page, [
        'path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
        'pageName' => 'page',
    ]);
    return view('backend/comments', compact('comments'));
```

Comment: What is the difference when i use the paginator with eloquent , in the case of eloquent i dont need to use $page, when the controller send with get page= 2 he automatically change de the information.

Comment: The Eloquent method User::paginate(15) will return a LengthAwarePaginator. What you were using, the Paginate object is returned by the User::simplePagination() method if I remember well... The LengthAwarePaginator is required if you want to deal with a known result set length...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your page name (the name of the request param denoting the page number) like so:

```
$products =  new Paginator($products, 10, null,
       ['path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
        'pageName' => 'page']);
```

Comment: I already made the change, but the result is the same, what else am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, where the data was not changing. I solved it by passing a page number to my guzzle call. Whenever a link is clicked, a request is sent therefore, you can get the page number from the request object. Pass the page number to the guzzle call so that the page number changes. Hope It helps